How do I add a text to screen with kivy?
Heres the code and I wanna add a text to the main screen, didnt fint the solution on the internet.  Help pls) Thanks)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Window.clearcolor = '#121212'
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Add the main and second screens to the manager, this class does nothing else
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen())
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen())
        sm.add_widget(ThirdScreen())
        return sm  # Return the manager to work with him later

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Main'  # setting the screen name value for the screen manager
        # (it's more convenient to call by name rather than by class)
        main_layout = FloatLayout()  # creating an empty layout that's not bound to the screen
        self.add_widget(main_layout)  # adding main_layout on screen

        # Button to get to the 2nd screen
        three_players = Button(text='3 players',
                            bold=True,
                            background_normal='',
                            background_color='#565656',
                            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35},
                            size_hint=(.7, .12),
                            color='#000000')
        three_players.bind(on_press=self.to_second_scrn)

        # Button to get to the 3rd screen
        four_players = Button(text='4 players',
                            bold=True,
                            background_normal='',
                            background_color='#565656',
                            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .2},
                            size_hint=(.7, .12),
                            color='#000000')
        four_players.bind(on_press=self.to_third_scrn)

        main_layout.add_widget(three_players)
        main_layout.add_widget(four_players) # adding button on layout

    def to_second_scrn(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'Second'  # selecting the screen by name (in this case by name "Second")

    def to_third_scrn(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'Third'  # selecting the screen by name (in this case by name "Thrid")

    def build(self):
        title = Label(text="ABOBA",
                      pos_hint={'center_x': 1, 'center_y': .9},
                      )

        return title

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    # on this screen, I do everything the same as on the main screen to be able to switch back and forth
        self.name = 'Second'
        second_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.add_widget(second_layout)

        Button
        Go_Back = Button(text='Go to Main screen',
                         size_hint=(.5, .5),
                         pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                         color='#ffff00')
        Go_Back.bind(on_press=self.to_main_scrn)

        second_layout.add_widget(Go_Back)

    def to_main_scrn(self, *args):  # together with the click of the button, it transmits info about itself.
        # In order not to pop up an error, add *args to the function
        self.manager.current = 'Main'
        return 0


class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    # on this screen, do everything the same as on the main screen to be able to switch back and forth
        self.name = 'Third'
        third_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.add_widget(third_layout)

        # Button
        Go_Back = Button(text='Go to Main screen',
                         size_hint=(.5, .5),
                         pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                         color='#ffff00')

        Go_Back.bind(on_press=self.to_main_scrn)

        third_layout.add_widget(Go_Back)

    def to_main_scrn(self, *args):  # together with the click of the button, it transmits info about itself.
        # In order not to pop up an error, add *args to the function
        self.manager.current = 'Main'
        return 0


sm = ScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()

Tried adding the new function to the MainApp class which returns label, but it didnt work.
But if I add it to the build function, it works, but nothing else does. hdddddddddddddddddddddddddd

You would use a Label to add text. Where do you want the text? Say more about what you are trying to achieve?

What do you mean by "hdddddddddddddddddddddddddd"?

What do you mean by "didn't work"? Please check [ask]

To add Label to the MainScreen from the App class, you need to access the widget tree and get the FloatLayout you've added to the screen, and add the Label widget to that Layout.
The App method on_start() is called after build is completed.  Add the code below to your App class, this will add the the Label to the MainScreen.
    def on_start(self):
        # get the main screen, FloatLayout
        main_screen_layout = self.root.get_screen('Main').children[0]
        main_screen_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Title", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .9}))


self is App
self.root is the ScreenManager
self.root.get_screen('Main') is the MainScreen instance
self.root.get_screen('Main').children[0] is the FloatLayout on the    MainScreen instance.

